# convert c++ primitive type vector to java primitive type array

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, primitive

I'm using a third party C++ API for my project and it has functions with return values with types `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<bool>`, `std::vector<double>`. I need to pass variables with these types to Java. So I'm using JNI and my function has return values with types `jintArray`, `jbooleanArray`, `jdoubleArray`.

I'm using following code to convert `double` type:

```
std::vector<double> data;
//fill data
jdouble *outArray = &data[0];
jdoubleArray outJNIArray = (*env).NewDoubleArray(data.size());  // allocate
if (NULL == outJNIArray) return NULL;
(*env).SetDoubleArrayRegion(outJNIArray, 0 , data.size(), outArray);  // copy
return outJNIArray;
```

I've no problem with this code block. But when I want to do this for `int` and `bool` types there is a problem at the following:

```
std::vector<int> data;
//fill data
jint *outArray = &data[0];
```

and

```
std::vector<bool> data;
//fill data
jboolean *outArray = &data[0];
```

The problem is with definitions of `jint` and `jboolean`, since:

```
typedef long            jint;
typedef unsigned char   jboolean;
```

and for `jdouble`:

```
typedef double          jdouble;
```

As, you can see my convenient solution for `double` doesn't work for `int` and `bool` types since their typedefs doesn't match.

So, my question is how can I do this conversion for all primitive types ***conveniently***?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data types might have different sizes you have to copy the vector. The simplest way to do this is

```
std::vector<jboolean> tmp(data.begin(), data.end());
jboolean *outArray = &tmp[0];
```

Of course, you can allocate the `jBooleanArray` and set the elements in a for loop or write a wrapper for it that behaves like an STL container.